# SpriteKit SKCropNode Masks everything

Tags: objective-c, ios8, sprite-kit, mask, skcropnode

I am trying to mask a node with SKCropNode class. I am doing it with my own init method in SKCropNode inherited class:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.maskNode = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[SKColor blackColor] size:(CGSize){50,50}];
        SKSpriteNode *contentNode = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        [self addChild: contentNode];

        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

It works as expected:
[image: Rectangle Mask]

Now, I want to add background to the scene and a cropped spaceship with following code:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    //
    //background
    //
    SKSpriteNode * background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background_game"];
    background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(view.frame), CGRectGetMidY(view.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(view.frame));

    [self addChild:background];

    TurretCropNode * cropNode = [[TurretCropNode alloc] init];
    cropNode.position = (CGPoint){view.frame.size.width/2,view.frame.size.height/2};
    [self addChild:cropNode];
}
```

I have just added few lines with adding background at the beginning (cropped node lines remain the same)

Here what I got now: [image: Background + mask]

Is it an expected behavior? Why cropped spaceship disappeared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that the image as shown below is your designated background. Have you checked your nodes `zPosition`?

If you want to show your spaceship infront of your background, you will have to adjust the `zPosition` to be higher than that of the background sprite.

Comment: Yeah, that was an issue. I thought if I added node as a child it automatically assigns the z-positions according to the order I added them. Thank you.